# Textview not changing appearance when using clickablespan

Tags: android, textview, android-recyclerview

I have the following `spantext` which is set to portion of a `TextView`.
 I have confirmed that the `TextView` is receiving the onClick input perfectly but the `TextView` is not changing it's **background color** until I either click the span a bunch of times (It varies) or scroll the `recyclerview` both in and out of view, but not too far because than it resets.

How can I get the `TextView`in the `recyclerview` to update immediately after the first click?

```
public class SpoilerSpan extends ClickableSpan {
    private boolean clicked = false;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        clicked = true;
        Log.d("Span", "Spoilerspan click registered")
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        if (!clicked){
            ds.setColor(Color.argb(255, 00, 00, 00)); //FF000000
            ds.bgColor = Color.argb(255, 00, 00, 00); //FF000000
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was really simple to fix

```
public class SpoilerSpan extends ClickableSpan {
    private boolean clicked = false;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        clicked = true;
        widget.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        if (!clicked){
            ds.setColor(Color.argb(255, 00, 00, 00)); //FF000000
            ds.bgColor = Color.argb(255, 00, 00, 00); //FF000000
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    }
}
```